# Restarting modem using cURL in PHP

Tags: php, curl, router, cisco

I have a Cisco EPC3825 modem. It needs to be rebooted daily or otherwise it will start performing slow. I did some digging in the source code of it and figured out that to login I need to post `username_login` and `password_login` fields to `/goform/Docsis_system`. From there I would navigate to Administration and Device restart and after that I would type in the password again and click restart. I thought I could just send the password to the form handler.

I came up with the following code.

```
<?php
$login = array(
    "username_login" => "username",
    "password_login" => "password"
);

$c = curl_init();

curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");

curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, "http://192.168.0.1/goform/Docsis_system");
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $login);

curl_exec($c);

$confirm = array(
    "devicerestrat_Password_check" => "password"
);

curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, "http://192.168.0.1/goform/Devicerestart");
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $confirm);

curl_exec($c);

curl_close($c);
?>
```

This one logs succesfully. I tried loading the main page from the router after the logging while `CURLOPT_POST` was set to 0. This one returned the page that is shown when the user is logged in.

The next part though won't work. How could I debug what it is doing? The return value of `curl_exec` is empty so echoing it doesn't do anything.

Note that the `devicerestrat_Password_check` in the `$confirm` array is typed correctly. That's a typo in the original code.

Comment: `devicerestrat_...`? `deviceRESTART`, perhaps (using caps to highlight the error).

Comment: @MarcB The last sentence in the post says that it is typed like that in the code.

Comment: I doubt cisco would release firmware with that blatant an error in it.

Comment: @MarcB http://pastebin.com/BCAvxcT2 Look at row 125.